# What were the origins of Persephone in The Matrix: Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix, the-matrix-reloaded

As shown in the movie Persephone was the wife of The Merovingian, who himself was an obsolete program who denied being deleted. My question is, does anybody know anything about the origins of Persephone? There seems to be no specific information that indicates who she previously was.

Comment: Did you mean origins in the myth sense?

Comment: Nope, I meant in the not-myth sense. I know that Persephone is the daughter of Zeus and blah blah blah...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us assume that the love that Persephone once enjoyed was with Merovingian.
Merovingian and Persephone have slightly more human traits than other programs, they enjoy fine food, wine, languages. While Persephone talks of love, Merovingian displays lust ("The lipstick that is not on Merovingian's face"). Merovingian is shown to cheat on Persephone. Surprisingly, he uses a special code to trigger sexual reactions in a woman and gets serviced by her! Persephone's envy leads her to give Neo and gang the Key Maker's location.

The Oracle mentions Merovingian to be the oldest of them, a powerful program.
No program other than the Oracle has the purpose to be human like.
The fact that Merovingian and Persephone turn human-like is them exhibiting programmatic roguishness.
Their initial purpose is not mentioned, but the period of love that Persephone mentions is when they went rogue. Merovingian controls the virtual afterlife through the train-man program. This is where exiled programs seek refuge.

Though this is the current operation, perhaps in the beginning, Merovingian was created with the purpose of Programmatic Garbage Collection. Once a program has served its purpose it needs to be de-allocated from the computing resource pool. (Eg: JVM provided by Java has a Garbage Collector which does a clean up periodically). The program Persephone was perhaps a supporting function to this Programmatic Garbage Collection, which is how they met.

Comment: `they enjoy fine food, wine, languages` Well, they enjoy very detailed computer simulations of them. Real humans who know they're in a computer program don't enjoy food or wine which suggests to me they're less than human.

Comment: Surely they are less human but they show traits of human behaviour (just like Ramachandran at the train station). My point was they are rogue programs. Besides, that is a side point. I was merely using that to deduce the origins of the programs.

Comment: @CrowTRobot  Cypher sure seemed to be enjoying that virtual steak..

Answer (score 15):

Persephone's origin is not mentioned in the movie. But she mentions about silver bullets, thus suggesting that Merovingian has a werewolf background. The DVD Behind the scenes mentions that she is a vampire that seeks after emotions.

She admires the love that Trinity and Neo hold for each other. She also mentions about the love that she had once enjoyed, which suggests that Merv was a better spouse before he is lost in his hunger and greed for power and lust. Hence she appears to be no more bothered about the matrix as well as Merv.

Comment: "Merv" - splendid!

Comment: In the Enter the Matrix videogame you fight your way through several werewolves guarding the Merovingian's château.